# How to root the SM-G900F Android 5.0 without tripping KNOX?

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-5, samsung-knox, warranty

I know the `Galaxy S5` can be rooted without tripping knox on `Android 4.4`. but that "bug" has been fixed by **Samsung**, and the developer of **TowelRoot** won't fix it because he works by **Google** now. So **TowelRoot** will not work for me because I have already updated to `Android 5.0`.

Is there any other possible solution to root the **Samsung Galaxy S5 G900F `Android 5.0`** without tripping the **KNOX WARRANTY VOID** to **0x1** or **1**.

---

Screenshot:

[image: About Phone]
(Touch for a larger image.)

---

Hope anybody will find a solution! Thanks!

**Edit:** Just updated my phone. Still on 5.0, updated the screenshot.

Comment: Well, I guess you got a pretty good change with the recently released [StageFright vulnerability](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2015/07/stagefright_vul.html). Unfortunately it's not yet disclosed but will be on the BlackHat conference. I'm pretty sure that once it's disclosed there will be some apps exploiting it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it following from this guide [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys5/comments/2ubsbs/guide_rooted_android_50_for_the_international/). Broadly (though I strongly suggest you follow the guide):

1) make backups

2) buy mobile Odin Pro from android market (5 USD)

3) downgrade using Odin (normal one on PC) to 4.4.

4) install towelroot and run it

5) use mobile Odin to flash rooted lollipop ROM *

6) use normal odin to flash compatible bootloader and modem.

*For some reason, using mobile Odin did not trip Knox when I did this, per the guide I linked. It still warned me that Knox would be tripped, even though it wasn't. I have no idea why it didn't trip Knox, so I can't guarantee it won't when you do it.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to think about it (because of the risk) and report to you later.

Comment: Alternatively you can just downgrade to 4.4 and root that, I don't think there is any risk there as I believe Knox allows you to downgrade without voiding the warranty, but don't quote me on it. And 4.4 is good enough for a year or so, and by then your warranty will have run out anyway so there will be nothing to lose by voiding it.