# Is it possible to root the Verizon Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900V) on Android 5.0 Lollipop?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I had root on 4.2 previously, but the update lost it, and with it my ability to use Sixaxis, AdFree, some features of NFC Tools and Tasker and Xposed modules.

I have searched, but it does not appear on this list:
[How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device/1185#1185)

I also saw a similar question here, but this is the AT&T version, not Verizon:
[How to root the SM-G900F Android 5.0 without tripping KNOX?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116438/how-to-root-the-sm-g900f-android-5-0-without-tripping-knox)

Towelroot doesn't work (just tried) and the SM-G900V isn't listed here: https://autoroot.chainfire.eu/

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Are you aware of Samsung's security features known as Knox ? .. Knox often causes undesirable effects on rooted Samsung devices that may make you reconsider having root access.

Comment: I may have heard of it in passing, but not sure to be honest.  That said I'm no longer on an S5 myself anyway, though I always hope people get an easy root solution for any phone.  I really don't get all the pushback from manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is a way out but it requires a bit of home work.

Towel root can only root Android KitKat so you've to downgrade to Android 4.4 and gain root access using Towel root.

Later you can upgrade to Android Lollipop 5.0 without loosing the root access.

If you like the idea here is the reference link to the guides given on the Xda developer forum.

Check post #2 http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-s5/help/verizon-galaxy-s5-lollipop-5-0-root-t3075261

Detail explanation of procedure of what I have said above: http://forum.xda-developers.com/verizon-galaxy-s5/general/how-to-update-to-g900voc4-5-0-keeproot-t3068546

I hope you find my answer helpful. Do let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you cannot root your phone the normal way, because Verizon won't let you unlock your bootloader. I believe [Kingroot](https://kingroot.net) should work. It was able to successfully root my Samsung Galaxy S3 running 4.4.4. If that doesn't work I would try [King**o**root](http://kingoapp.com). Hope this helps. We all hate Verizon for keeping our bootloaders locked.

Answer (score -1):

kingo root. Download the windows version run it and then tether your phone in debug mode.